# Phonegap iOS app using PHP and MySQL. How to setup?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ios, cordova

Right now I'm building my first iOS app using Phonegap. This is because I wanna use PHP and MySQL databases. I got started and it kind of works.

But now, I got a really basic question...

Is it possible to just use the jQuery function .load() to load the first page of a PHP-application, that is located on my web server, and then use and post go thru a login process. I tried, and it seems to be working.

But I imagine there will be a lot of downsides?
Like, would I be able to access the deviceid and geolocation plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you develop your application using PhoneGap as a wrapper you can be able to access a wide range of device features such as camera, accelerometer, geolocation etc. PhoneGap comes with JavaScript module that you can use to query device features and use them.